# Midori automatically closes

Tags: browser

I use Midori a lot, but I have one big problem with it: It won't stop automatically closing! When I'm in the middle of a YouTube video, Midori just closes itself and I have to start over! Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Is there an error log?